# Inserting xls data into Oracle DB using cx_Oracle executemany

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert an xls file into oracle table using cx_Oracle. Below is the way how I am trying to achieve the same.

```
wb = open_workbook('test.xls')
    values=[]
    sheets=wb.sheet_names()
xl_sheet=wb.sheet_by_name(s)
    sql_str=preparesql('MATTERS') ##this is function I have created which will return the insert statement I am using to load the table
    for row in range(1, xl_sheet.nrows):
        col_names = xl_sheet.row(0)
        col_value = []
        for name, col in zip(col_names, range(xl_sheet.ncols)):
            searchObj = re.search( (r"Open Date|Matter Status Date"), name.value, re.M|re.I)
            if searchObj:                           
                if (xl_sheet.cell(row,col).value) == '':
                    value = ''
                else:
                    value = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(xl_sheet.cell(row,col).value, wb.datemode))
                    value = value.strftime('%d-%b-%Y ')
            else:
                value = (xl_sheet.cell(row,col).value)
            col_value.append(value)
        values.append(col_value)

    cur.executemany(sql_str,values,batcherrors=True)
```

But When I tested it against multiple xls files  for some files it was throwing TypeError: I can't share the data due to the restrictions from the client.I feel the issue is related to the dtype of the columns in excel compared to the DB. Is there any way I can match the dtpes of the values list above to match the datatype of the columns in DB or are there any other ways to get the insert done? I tried using the dataframe.to_sql but it is taking lot of time. I am able to insert  the same data by looping through the rows in values list.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: expecting float

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you import data into panda dataframe than it become very easy to play with data type in pandas. You can change the data type of whole column and than can insert easily.